# Angular Materials 6.3.0 Dialog is not center align after update?

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog, angular-material2, angular-material-6

I've used angular `Dialog` with 6.2.1 materials version, it was OK.

I just updated to 6.3.0.
Now All of my `Dialog`s are right align, not center !

[image: Angular Material dialog]

What's wrong !

**Update:**

I found what causes this problem.
Whenever I set `dir="rtl"` in html tag, problem occurred.
How can I fix it?

Comment: post some code please.

Comment: You can find the same problem here https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/11393

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. We can resolve this problem as follows:

from  https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#specifying-global-configuration-defaults

> Specifying global configuration defaults Default dialog options can be
>   specified by providing an instance of MatDialogConfig for
>   MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS in your application's root module.

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {hasBackdrop: true, direction: 'ltr'}}
  ]
})
```

Notice to `direction: 'ltr'`

Comment: I was searching for a solution for so long, and this helped, Thanks.